# How to enable swap/swapfile on Google container optimized OS on GCE?

Tags: swapfile, google-container-os

Using the `cos-stable` container optimized OS on GCE. Micro instance so ram is pretty sparse. Tried to enable swap to prevent locking due to OOM during docker pulls, but can't get it to work.

I realize most folders are stateless, so I put the swapfile under home:

```
sudo fallocate -l 1G /home/user/swapfile
sudo chmod 600 /home/user/swapfile
sudo mkswap /home/user/swapfile
```

results in:

```
Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 1024 MiB (1073737728 bytes)
no label, UUID=6e965805-2ab9-450f-aed6-577e74089dbf
```

But `sudo swapon /home/user/swapfile` gives the error:

```
swapon: /home/user/swapfile: swapon failed: Invalid argument
```

Any ideas how to enable swap on COS?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Disk based swap is disabled in the COS image.
You can enable disk based swap with

`sysctl vm.disk_based_swap=1`

I have the following in my cloud-init:

```
bootcmd:
- sysctl vm.disk_based_swap=1
- fallocate -l 1G /var/swapfile
- chmod 600 /var/swapfile
- mkswap /var/swapfile
- swapon /var/swapfile
```

Comment: Woah, nice. I'll have to try that out. Thanks so much.

Comment: Is this an older version of COS? When I run the first line, I get the following: ```-bash: sysctl: command not found```

Comment: @AreToo After executing all the commands under ssh, I've added custom metadata key `startup-script` to the COS instance with these value: `sysctl vm.disk_based_swap=1; sudo swapon /PATH_TO_YOUR/swapfile`

Answer (score 3):

Swap is not supported in container optimized OS

Swap would effectively destroy much of the behavioral isolation Google offers between containers.

Guaranteed pods should never require swap. Burstable pods should have their requests met without requiring swap. BestEffort pods have no guarantee.

I highly suggest you use a bigger instance as a [f1-micro](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types#sharedcore) only has 600MB of RAM and you still need to run the OS on the instance it addition with your containers

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm not using k8s. It's just a single vm running a few docker containers managed by docker compose. Can't switch to a bigger instance because the project requires to be in the always free tier. I find it interesting that such a minimal OS with hardly any packages built in includes swapon but doesn't support swap. Perhaps I should use a different distro as swap is critical during those rare memory spikes

Comment: I understand your limitations, you should use a different OS I’ve tested the steps to add swap memory in GCP with Ubuntu and CoreOS, it works as you expect
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq

Comment: "I highly suggest you use to switch from free tier to paid tier" - okay. Personally I just switched to Ubuntu.